# Open Graph actions not shown in news feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, feed

I just established an app which is my personal blog on Facebook. I have had action "Publish" approved and it says this action type is now available to all users. But when I publish a new post from my blog, it only shows in my timeline, nothing gets displayed in the news feed, and I asked my friend to check their news feed, they got nothing. Can anyone help me with this? I have been stuck since yesterday. Many thanks!

My blog is built upon Wordpress, but I think it is something to do with the OG API. Please help!!

Michael

Answer (score 2):

You have to activate [explicit sharing](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/guides/explicit-sharing/) for your action. Then it will be shown up as a normal posting of a user.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook controls everything about what will be shown in the news feed. Check if the action is shown in the Ticker. If the actions is shown in the ticker, it's OK.
If your app gets more popular, the priority to be shown in the news feed may increase.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to check if other users are seeing your actions is to go to **Insights** > **Open Graph** > **Story CTR** and see if your action is getting impressions.

You should also drop by **Action Lifecycle** and check how many actions are being created and compare that with your internal number just to make sure that all the actions are being picked up.

Based on what you are saying, you might be using the "Publish" action when a post is made on your blog. If you are the only person posting, chances of those stories appearing in your friends' feeds is very small. You might consider using Open Graph for something that multiple users/readers can do on your site.